# How to add a Line to a RichEdit component in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have created a signup form using delphi 2010, i wanted to not let my already existing user signups using their email. So if any signup with an already registered email will Show up the form pass_reset dialog.

```
 uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, StdCtrls, GIFImg, ExtCtrls, pngimage, ComCtrls, FMTBcd, WideStrings,
DBXMySql, DB, SqlExpr, MessageDigest_5, Types, ShellAPI, IdBaseComponent,
IdComponent, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL,
IdSSLOpenSSL, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase,
IdMessageClient, IdSMTPBase, IdSMTP, IdMessage,**pass_reset;**

{Checking wether email exist}

SQLQuery2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * from registered where email="'+email+'"';
SQLQuery2.Open;
count := SQLQuery2.RecordCount;

{if email exit bfore display message already exist}

if (count>0) then
begin
PassReset.Show;
end;
```

How to write in the pass_reset form

sorry email@exemple.com  is already in our database,  (using TRichEdit component)

Something like

```
 procedure TPassReset.Rich_customExistBeforeChange(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 email := form_signup.ed_email.text;
 RichEdit1.Append('Hello "'+email+'" it seem that you''re already registered with us');
 end;
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You mean you don't know how to go `RichEdit.Lines.Add('My message with rich formatting');`

Comment: It's RichEdit.Lines.Add, not RichEdit1.Append. You are modifying the Lines property, not the RichEdit control.

Comment: It's workiçng ok when used as Click event of some button but Where to put this line of code in order to auto change on the form creation i tried with FormCreate but it didn't work

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't work from FormCreate, unless you have some code later that clears or assigns the same thing, wiping out what you did. You have to debug your own code. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
RichEdit1.Lines.Add('sorry email@exemple.com is already in our database');
```

It will add one line to the TRichEdit `RichEdit1`.

Assuming that your code `PassReset.Show` works you can modify your TRichEdit from the same place.

```
if (count>0) then
begin
  PassReset.Show;
  PassReset.RichEdit1.Lines.Add('sorry email@exemple.com is in use');
end;
```